# Integers and/or array of integers into a single int array using variadic function

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a function, with a variable number of integer/int array parameters, that concatenates all the elements into a single 1-dimensional array. I'm struggling with one of the two scenarios where current_item turns out to be an array instead of just an integer. How can I access the individual elements of this array and assign them to pOutList?

```
typedef unsigned short      WORD;

int PinListJoin(WORD * pOutList, ...) {

    int index=0;
    boolean isArray = false;

    va_list next_item;
    va_start(next_item, pOutList);
    WORD current_item = va_arg(next_item, WORD);
    int current_item_size = sizeof(current_item) / sizeof(WORD);

    if (current_item_size > 1) {
        isArray = true;
        for (int pinidx = 0; pinidx < current_item_size; pinidx++) {
            pOutList[index] = current_item;
            index++;
        }
    }
    else {
        isArray = false;
        pOutList[index] = current_item;
        index++;
    }

    va_end(next_item);

    return(current_item_size);

}
```

Comment: You should be using C++ templates, instead of C's variadic parameter hacks. As shown, this cannot actually be done with C's variadic parameter hack, since your C function has no knowledge, whatsoever, however many actual parameters it received. It must deduce it, somehow, which gets messy, and is error prone. On the other hand, this is exactly what C++ templates are for. Have you considered using proper C++ templates, instead of the prehistoric C variadic parameter macros? You should realize that the shown code is fatally flawed, because `current_item_size` will always be obviously 1.

Comment: It's completely new to me, variadic template. Looking at some examples right now.

Comment: Finding [examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) is easy...once you know 2) what you're looking for and 2) where to look for it :D.

Comment: What I know at the moment is to declare as follows:

template<typename Arg1, typename... Args>
int PinListJoin(Arg1 pOutList, Args ...args)

I'm struggling on definition. and grappling with the idea that recursion is necessary

Comment: So, do I need to define both the "base case" and the "recursive case" functions?

Comment: Yes, I believe recursion is how that is usually handled. It's technically a "specialization" of the vardic function, I believe.

Comment: You seem to be writing C code, not C++ code.  If that is your intent, you should change the tag.

Comment: What you need to do is [to read a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains how to use parameter packs. This is one of the most complicated parts of C++, and simply cannot be fully explained in a brief one or two paragraph answer on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> boolean isArray = false;
> ```

There is no `boolean` datatype in C++.

Also, the value of neither `isArray` nor `index` variable is ever used in the function.

> ```
> typedef unsigned short      WORD;
> WORD current_item = va_arg(next_item, WORD);
> ```

This isn't going to work. Variadic arguments are promoted. `unsigned short` promotes to `int` (typically; on some exotic system, it might be `unsigned int`). Using the non-promoted type with `va_arg` will cause undefined behaviour. You could use a trick like this to get the correct type for any system:

```
using promoted_word = decltype(+WORD(0));
WORD current_item = WORD(va_arg(next_item, promoted_word));
```

> ```
> WORD current_item = va_arg(next_item, WORD);
> int current_item_size = sizeof(current_item) / sizeof(WORD);
> ```

The size of `WORD` divided by the  size of `WORD` is always 1. There's no point in doing this.

> I'm struggling with one of the two scenarios where current_item turns out to be an array instead of just an integer. How can I access the individual elements of this array and assign them to pOutList?

Function argument cannot be an array. But it can be a pointer to an element of an array, which I assume is what you mean. If that is the case, then you can get the pointer out of varargs like this:

```
WORD* current_item = va_arg(next_item, WORD*);
```

You can then copy the elements from array to array just like you would using any pointer to an element.

There's still two problems though: 1. There is no way of finding out the size of the array based on that pointer and 2. There is no way of finding out what type of arguments were passed (i.e. whether it was a( pointer to a)n array or an integer). You can take a look at the interface of `printf` for an idea of how that problem may be solved. It is solved there using a format string where those types are specified. The length of the array is solved by using a sentinel value (the null terminator character). Another approach is to pass the length as a separate argument.

---

More generally though: I recommend that you not use C style varargs at all in C++. It's just too easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Variadic templates are much safer and more powerful way to achieve similar things.

That said, I don't quite understand what you're attempting to do, so I cannot confirm whether it makes sense to use any form of variadics.